# How to put an element from an array infront of another element.?

Tags: c++

How to put an element from array in front of an another element of same array.(//and not exchanging their positions !!)
For ex...
57364
35764 (3 infront of 5)
35674 (6 infront of 7)
34567 (4 in frontof 5)

Comment: But.. If you put an element in front of some other element, the position of every element past your insertion point, must change..

Comment: Then let it change the position

Comment: In that case it is simple, move every element, after the insertion point by 1 position towards the end, followed by insertion of the element. What exactly, is unclear about that? Or better yet, just use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of trying reinvent the (part of its) functionality.

Comment: Use `std::rotate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic, in-place solution might be:

```
#include<vector>
#include<cassert>
#include<algorithm>

// random iterator, the behaviour is undefined if first == second, or
// first and second do not belong to some valid range
template<typename RIter>
void move_in_front_of( RIter first, RIter second )
{
  std::iter_swap(first,second);

  if( first < second )
    std::rotate(std::next(first),second,std::next(second));
  else
    std::rotate(std::next(second),first,std::next(first));
}

int main()
{
  auto v1 = std::vector<int>{5,7,3,6,4};
  auto v2 = std::vector<int>{3,5,7,6,4};
  auto v3 = std::vector<int>{3,5,6,7,4};
  auto v4 = std::vector<int>{3,4,5,6,7};

  move_in_front_of( v1.begin()+2, v1.begin() );//3,5
  assert( v1 == v2 );
  move_in_front_of( v1.begin()+3, v1.begin()+2 );//6,7
  assert( v1 == v3 );
  move_in_front_of( v1.begin()+4, v1.begin()+1 );//4,5
  assert( v1 == v4 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this program takes array position to determine front and back element.

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int length=10;
    int arr[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    void infront(int front, int back);

    int main()
    {
        int front,back;     //(front infront of back)
        cout<<"array is: ";
        for(int i=0; i<length;i++)
            cout<<arr[i]<<',';
        cout<<"enter position of front element";
        cin>>front;
        cout<<"Enter position of back element";
        cin>>back;

        infront(front,back);

        cout<<"array is: ";
        for(int i=0; i<length;i++)
            cout<<arr[i]<<',';
    }
    void infront(int front, int back)
    {
        int temp,i;
        temp=arr[front];
        if(back < front)
        {
            for(i=front;i<back-1;i++)
            {
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            }
            arr[i]=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            for(i=front;i>back;i--)
            {
                arr[i]=arr[i-1];
            }
            arr[i]=temp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Can be optimised.. this time in c++. exchange_index is the index of the number you want to move to insertion_index.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int a[5] = {3,5,6,7,4};

    int exchange_index = 2;
    int exchange_val = a[exchange_index];
    int insertion_index = 3;

    if(exchange_index > insertion_index) {
        for(int i=exchange_index;i>insertion_index;i--) {
            a[i] = a[i-1];
        }
    } 
    else {
        for(int i=exchange_index;i<insertion_index;i++) {
            a[i] = a[i+1];
        }
    }

    a[insertion_index] = exchange_val;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        cout << a[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why in the world do you post a JavaScript answer to a C++ question?

Comment: @Christian Hackl - Sorry about that. Thought it was a generic problem.. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code ! . It is working fine.
I am also attached the screenshort of the code .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // integer array
    int arr[10] = { 3, 1, 6, 78, 5, 3, 7, 90 };

    //size of the current array
    int n = 8;

    //num varaible is used to take the input of front element of the array that you want 
    //val varaible is used to take the input that you want to inserted in the array
    //flag variable indicates the front element 'num' is found in array or not 
    //index varaible is used to keep the index of array where 'num' value found
    int num, val, flag = 0, index;


    //before inserted , prints the array values
    cout << "\t\t Array values" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }


    //taking front value input from the user through keyboard 
    cout << "\nEnter front element of the array :";
    cin >> num;

    //taking inserted value input from the user
    cout << "\nEnter element that are inserted infront of " << num << " :";
    cin >> val;


    //finding the index of front value in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == num)
        {
            index = i;
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }


    //inserted in the array infront of 'num' value
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        // if front value found in the array
        for (int i = n; i > index; i--)
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i-1];
        }
        arr[index] = val;
        cout << "\nInserted successfully ....!"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // when front value not found in the array
        cout << "\nFront element not found ... !"<<endl;
    }


    // after successfull insertion , prints the array 
    cout << "\n\t\t Array values" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output of the code]